# A RepleyMessage cannt be creted on an ExecutionSpecification without receiving event

Tags: sequence-diagram

I am using the `Astah` editor  to build sequence digram for my system component and I  want to add return message from `Database` to `Receiver` at the end of the diagram after `getRouteNumber` but I am getting `A RepleyMessage cannt be creted on an ExecutionSpecification without receiving event`. How can I add return message from `Dataase` to `Receiver` after the `getRouteNumber()` method?

I  have already added once from `Analyzer` to `Behaviour` and once from `Behaviour` to `Database`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to correct the step I provided in my previous answer. I am very sorry for making you confused.

To add Return message from Database to Behaviour, please follow the step below.

(1) Select an allow-head of "1.1.1: connectBehaviour()" and drag it to the top of Execution Specification of "2: drivercConnecion" and drop it. (Please see the picture from the URL below)
https://changevision.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/move_arrow.png

(2) Click on the [Reply Messgae]​ button on Main tool bar and then add the return message from Database to Receiver.(Please see the picture from the URL below)
https://changevision.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/add_return.png

Comment: @Kaoria: Sorry I had one mistake in my question since I want to add return message from `Database` to `Receiver`. I had it in other sentence correct.

Comment: @MrAsker I corrected the step I provided in my previous answer. Please check the step above. I apologize for making you confused..